# Буква двумя цветами

Tags: css3, html, css

Здравствуйте!
Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать с помощью css букву двумя цветами? Как на картинке http://prntscr.com/5uteo7 .
Спасибо.

Comment: @kamila, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/UNm8H/) Найдено на stackoverflow

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: В примере 2 цвета, а на вашем скрине градиент - сверху и красный - снизу.

Comment: @aaliseyko присмотритесь повнимательнее - там нет градиента

Comment: Куда уж внимательнее: оранжевая часть на скрине. Самый верхнии пиксель: #FDBF58, а самый же нижний, перед красной областью: #F87E32. Это что по вашему, если не градиент?

Answer (score 0):

Наложить друг на друга position: absolute; две копии слова, одну "укоротить" на нужную высоту, добавить нужные градиенты для каждого + z-index для надежности.